# Is there any character restrictions for the Desc field for LineItemAdd on QBXML

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am getting a generic looking error for this InvoiceAddRq

```
0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.
```

The only out-of-the-ordinary part of the xml seems to be the LineItem Description (contains `/` and `&` characters):

```
<InvoiceLineAdd>
        <ItemRef>
            <FullName>Other</FullName>
        </ItemRef>
        <Desc>Memorial Installation/Layout Inspection fee for John & Jane Doe by Acme Monuments</Desc>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Amount>300.00</Amount>
        <SalesTaxCodeRef>
            <FullName>NON</FullName>
        </SalesTaxCodeRef>
    </InvoiceLineAdd>
```

The 'Onscreen Reference for Intuit Software Development Kits' says that `Desc` is of the `STRTYPE` and can be up to 4000 characters

I can't seem to figure what is triggering this error?  All my other Invoices seems to be going in just find.

**New Attempt:**
@William Lorfing suggested encoding, so I used PHP `htmlentities()` on the `Desc` input which sent this:

```
 <Desc>Memorial Installation/Layout Inspection fee for John &amp; Jane Smith by Acme Monuments</Desc>
```

Is there a different PHP encoding that could maybe be needed for the forward slash also?

Comment: As I posted this, I vaguely remember someone stating that this error may be a result of PHP output during the xml request.  I am checking now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using encoding. See Consolibyte site for details - http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml_questions

Comment: I ended up needing to replace the '/' character also.  Thank you